# SCR service issue in OBR

Tags: osgi, obr

Services delared via SCR do not get reflected in the OBR xml as a capability while those with Blueprint do (I am building via Maven Bundle Plugin).

The tag below as an example does NOT appear in the xml for a bundle with SCR services:

```
<capability name='service'>
      <p n='service' v='com.abc.xyz'/>
    </capability>
```

By adding the "Export-Service" header, we get the capability tag in OBR for the SCR service, but the "Export-Service" header is deprecated. 
The OBR deploy fails when there is a requirement for a service in a particular bundle and the capability is not found.

Comment: Are you sure that the Blueprint services are output in the OBR XML?? I have never seen this... and I'm the maintainer (though not original author) of the bindex project that generates the OBR XML.

Comment: Yes, blueprint services are output as service capabilities in obr xml